# Move source file location outside Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I want to group some source file into a folder for better organization, but visual studio will not recognize them once they are moved, the file path cannot be changed from VS inside (at least I don't know if there is a way to do so). Is there a better way other than excluding the file and re-adding them again? It's very tedious painful to do so once you have a lot of files. Any suggestions?

For example in my solution I have `stdafx.h`, `stdafx.cpp` and `resource.h` directly under the root directory while in VS it displayed under a header folder. What I wanted to do is to create a actual Header folder under root directory and move them into that folder.

Edit:
If I do so by excluding and re-including files during build time I get this error:

```
cannot overwrite information formed during creation of the precompiled header in object file stdafx.obj
```

This `stdafx.h` file is automatically there along with the creation of a win32 application project, I heard that I should create precompiled header file under setting. So I set `stdafx.cpp` to `Yc` (create precompiled header) and set all the other .cpp file to `Yu` (use precompiled header). But while building error message saying `fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stdafx.h'`. But the fact is that `stdafx.h` is right under the Header folder in the root directory and is included from that folder and it could be opened in VS, but there is still read lines under that include statement and hence the error.

Comment: You can Cut-Paste files from within VS2012.

Comment: @Tilak this will only affect the group structure on VS itself and the actual physical location is not affected.

Comment: It will if you do inside projects. It will not work under solutions. Solution items are different

Comment: @Tilak not sure if I follow, by copying pasting the source file into a different folder in VS the actual folder is not affected. For example in my solution I have `stdafx.h`, `stdafx.cpp` and `resource.h` directly under the root directory while in VS it displayed under a header folder. What I wanted to do is to create a actual Header folder under root directory and move them into that folder. I can only do this by moving outside VS.

Answer (score 1):

You can manually edit the *vcxproj and *sln files, they are plain xml files. Look up the entries of your moved files in those xml files and correct the paths to match the directories where you put them. This might be a bit tedious but only applies if you restructure your folders manually like you did.